# bar chart dynamic reference line length

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a reference line in a bar chart, but I want that line to adjust dynamically based on the index length of the x-axis. I'd like the line to start at the left edge of the left-most bar and end at the right edge of the right-most bar. I've noticed that when the value for ind (index) varies, I cannot accurately make the adjustment by using a percentage of ind or a constant for xmin and xmax arguments.

Here's an example slightly modified from the matplotlib site:
http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/bar_stacked.html

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


N = 5
menMeans = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
womenMeans = (25, 32, 34, 20, 25)
menStd = (2, 3, 4, 1, 2)
womenStd = (3, 5, 2, 3, 3)
ind = np.arange(N)    # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars: can also be len(x) sequence

p1 = plt.bar(ind, menMeans, width, color='r', yerr=menStd)
p2 = plt.bar(ind, womenMeans, width, color='y',
             bottom=menMeans, yerr=womenStd)

#How do I adjust the length of this line dynamically?
plt.axhline(linewidth=1, color='b', y=np.average(menMeans))
plt.ylabel('Scores')
plt.title('Scores by group and gender')
plt.xticks(ind + width/2., ('G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5'))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 81, 10))
plt.legend((p1[0], p2[0]), ('Men', 'Women'))

plt.show()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I added an answer, but I'm not sure this is what you meant. Let me know if you need something else.

Comment: Thanks, Andras. I tried this (without the extra bracket before the *2) but I got the error: x and y must have the same first dimension.

Comment: I realized that I needed to duplicate y, as you mentioned, and all went well.

Comment: So if this was indeed what you needed, please consider marking my answer as accepted:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the explicitly defined `width` parameter of the `bar` plot to manually draw a line which suits your needs:

```
p1 = plt.bar(ind, menMeans, width, color='r', yerr=menStd)
p2 = plt.bar(ind, womenMeans, width, color='y',
         bottom=menMeans, yerr=womenStd)

#line with adjusted length
plt.plot([min(ind), max(ind)+width], np.average(menMeans)]*2,linewidth=1,color='b')
```

We just define a pair of `x` and `y` coordinates to generate the line as a `plot`. The `x` is given by `[min(ind), max(ind)+width]`, and the `y` is a duplicate vector with values `np.average(menMeans)`. The proper `x` values can be inferred from the fact that your example code places the `xtick`s at `ind+width/2`, and we know that the bars' width is exactly `width`.

Result:

[image: bar plot with adjusted horizontal line]